# Определять количество коллизий в unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, хеширование, unordered-map

Подскажите, как можно реализовать функцию подсчета коллизий в тексте? Подразумевается хранить слова по хэшу в `unordered_map<size_t, unordered_set<string>>`
Хэшер передается параметром. Под коллизией имеется ввиду ситуация когда прочитано слово, которое ранее не встречалось, но хэш совпадает с хэшем одного из предыдущих.

````
template <typename Hash>
int CollisionsCounter(const Hash& hasher, istream& text) {

}

struct Hasher {
    size_t operator() (const string& str) const {
        size_t result = 0;
        for (char c : str) {
            result += static_cast<size_t>(c);
        }
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    hash<string> hasher;
    int collisions = CollisionsCounter(hasher, cin);
    cout << "total collisions: "s << collisions << endl;
} ```
````

Comment: Посмотрите на [`load_factor()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/load_factor) - вас это интересует? Или вам надо для каждого значения хеша количество коллизий? Тогда смотрите раздел "Bucket interface" [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: @Harry да, именно количество для каждого значения интересует, спасибо. Насколько я понял нужно проверять каждый элемент на bucket size > 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотреть на количество коллизий можно с использованием функций [`bucket_`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). Например,

```
unordered_set<int> m;
m.max_load_factor(10);
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) m.insert(i);
cout << "Bucket count: " << m.bucket_count() << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < m.bucket_count(); ++i)
    cout << i << ":  " << m.bucket_size(i) << endl;
```

(Я специально указал большой `max_load_factor`, чтобы коллизий было побольше. И использовал `unordered_set` — он в этом отношении ничем не отличается от `unordered_map`.)

Вот как это выглядит с использованием своей (жуткой... :)) функции хеширования:

```
struct myHash
{
    size_t operator()(int i) const
    {
        return i%3;
    };
};

int main()
{
    unordered_set<int,myHash> m;
    m.max_load_factor(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) m.insert(i);
    cout << "Bucket count: " << m.bucket_count() << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < m.bucket_count(); ++i)
        cout << i << ":  " << m.bucket_size(i) << endl;
}
```